# Checking if strings exist in a file (ksh)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

What this KornShell (ksh) script should do is check in my dmesg for disks, internals and externals. On the dmesg output, internal drives appear as wd[0-9] and externals as sd[0-9]. I of course do not have so many disks but I want my script to cover as many possibilities as possible. Devices 0-9 will be checked. So this is the idea:

create two arrays of size 9, search through dmesg if wd0 exists, if so make the first element of internals 1, if wd1 does exist make the second element of array 1 or 0 otherwise.

If it was to search for one specific disk e.g. wd0, I could do something like:

```
internal=`dmesg | grep "^wd0" | head -n 1 | cut -d\  -f1`
```

which makes

```
internal = wd0
```

But how to check if the strings wd0-wd9 exists in the dmesg in a "loopy" way

```
# create arrays
set -A internals 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
set -A externals 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

(the code below is not ksh code, but presenting the idea in c-like syntax):

```
for (i=0;i<=8;i++){
    if (wd0) # that is if wd0 exists, if wd1 exists etc.
        internal[i] = 1;
    else
        internal[i] = 0;
}
```

And of course the same process should be followed for the externals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should get you going, not exactly sure what values you want your arrays set to but here goes:

```
#!/bin/ksh

set -A internal 

for i in {0..9}
do
   echo "Looking for wd"$i
   internal[$i]=`dmesg | grep "^wd$i" | head -n 1 | cut -d\  -f1`
   if [[ ${internal[$i]} = "wd"$i ]];then
     internal[$i]=1
   else
     internal[$i]=0
   fi
done
```

Comment: Almost what i needed, I'll change it to my needs. Thanks. :)